# FluentAssertions without exceptions?

Tags: fluent-assertions

This seems like a long shot...

I am building a test harness for manual testing (for my QA Team).  It runs in a console application and can output some level of smart data, but nothing so automatic as a fully automated test (not my rules).

I would love to use FluentAssertions to generate the text to show, but I don't want to throw an exception.

**Is there a way to have FluentAssertions just output a string with its fluent message?** (Without throwing an exception.)

NOTE: I am aware of a possible workaround: (Try/Catch statements around an `AssertionScope` around my fluent assertion checks).  But I am hoping to keep the extra code to a minimum so as to not confuse the non-programmer QA person that has to use the test harness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the `Services.ThrowException` property with custom behavior or you could use `AssertionScope`'s `Discard` method.